# Changing multiple offsets in a VBA loop

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I am trying to run a loop where for each account in a range the account number is sent out to a program to search for data. This data is input to another Excel sheet, formatted, and then printed to PDF. This data can only be fetched by one account at a time, so I need it to run through and after saving one pdf to either clear the data and do it again for the next account etc. This process can take a while and so what I am trying to do is create a percentage complete cell.

Is there a way to recognize how many times through the loop it needs to run (say 10) and then update a cell saying we are on loop 1 of 10, 2 of 10, etc.

Here is the code I am running right now:

```
Public Sub Eligibility()
    Dim a As Range, ws As Worksheet
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Starting Page")
    
    '************* This is the loop to check the cells and set the offset value as elgible or ineligible**********
        
    For Each a In ws.Range("G9:G29").Cells
        If a.Value = Eligible Then
         a.Offset(0, -1).Value = AccountNumber(a.Value)
            Data_Import
            End If
    Next a
    
    '************* Question if we will printscreen**********
    
Dim AnswerYes As String
Dim AnswerNo As String

AnswerYes = MsgBox("Do you want to print all eligible class action reports?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo, "User Response")
If AnswerYes = vbYes Then Print_PDF
    
End Sub
```

G9:G29 is the range and so I wonder if the number could look at that range and tell how many instances of "eligible" there is for the denominator on the count.

Comment: Do a `countif` on `Eligible` for `g9:g29` and increment that?

Comment: To do that in sync with the loop would I need to do a Do While loop? I cant get my head around how to get those together.

Comment: Set it to a variable before then you can just increment it within your `for` loop. Edit: instead of a cell, I would use `application.statusbar` that displays current loop number.

Comment: run through the loop adding each of the eligible cells to a VBA collection, then you can get the count of items in the collection (total eligible cells)  then use a FOR loop to loop through the items in the collection doing the actual work.  percentage complete will be i/count

Comment: @JoeBourne This sounds right but that went a good amount over my head. I dont think I have messed with "collections" before. Or am I just overthinking this? Sorry!!

Comment: @Wallenbees, i posted an untested example showing how you could add all the eligible cells to the new VBA collection then loop over the collection.

Answer (score 0):

Run through the loop adding each of the eligible cells to a VBA collection, then you can get the count of items in the collection (total eligible cells) then use a FOR loop to loop through the items in the collection doing the actual work. percentage complete will be i/count
Something like this (totally untested!)

```
Public Sub Eligibility()
    Dim a As Range, ws As Worksheet
    Dim oEligibleCells As VBA.Collection
    Dim i As Long
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Starting Page")
    
    '************* This is the loop to check the cells and set the offset value as elgible or ineligible**********
    Set oEligibleCells = New VBA.Collection
    For Each a In ws.Range("G9:G29").Cells
        If a.Value = Eligible Then
            Call oEligibleCells.Add(a)
        End If
    Next a
    
    For i = 1 To oEligibleCells.Count
        Set a = oEligibleCells(i)
        a.Offset(0, -1).Value = AccountNumber(a.Value)
        Data_Import
        Application.StatusBar = i / oEligibleCells.Count * 100 & " percent done"
    Next i
    
    '************* Question if we will printscreen**********
    
Dim AnswerYes As String
Dim AnswerNo As String

AnswerYes = MsgBox("Do you want to print all eligible class action reports?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo, "User Response")
If AnswerYes = vbYes Then Print_PDF
    
End Sub
```